# In Ext.js4.1.3, how to find a combobox related to its internal item?

Tags: combobox, extjs4.1

I have a [ComboBox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox) subclass which has a customized template for rendering its data. Once one internal list item is clicked, there is a listener to the **browser "click" event**, which needs to make some changes on the original combobox.

How can I find a reference to its related combobox from this listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the customized combo contents was defined using [listConfig](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-listConfig) and its `click` listener was defined through the [listeners](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundList-cfg-listeners) config, `this` refers to the boundList element in the scope of the `listener`. A more simple way to reach the same result:

```
click:{
    element:'el',
    fn: function(ev, target) {  //listener
        var boundList= Ext.getCmp(this.id),
        combobox= boundList && boundList.getBubbleParent();
        //Do something with the combobox, like changing its value
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found, which answers my question.

From the "click" listener 2nd argument, we [get](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext-method-get) the click event target [element](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element). We can then [navigate](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.dom.AbstractElement-method-findParentNode) to its parent [boundlist](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundList) element, using the .x-boundlist class, [get](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp) its component and finally reach the combobox through its not-documented pickerField property or its [getBubbleTarget()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-getBubbleTarget) method.

```
click:{
    element:'el',
    fn: function(ev, target) {  //listener
        var el= Ext.get(target),
            boundList_el, boundList, combobox;         
        boundList_el= el && el.findParentNode(".x-boundlist");
        boundList= boundList_el && Ext.getCmp(boundList_el.id);
        combobox= boundList && boundList.getBubbleParent();
        //Do something with the combobox, like changing its value
    }
```